# Creating a resource file to use it in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, pyqt, resources, qt-designer, rcc

I want to add a background image to a widget and thus I need a resource file but I am not able to create it in Qt Designer. Here is what I did:

1. From the widget I go to the resources browser and click on the "add new file" button then a new window pops up.
2. I am asked to point to the .qrc file but this file does not exist and I don't know how to create it.

I googled and found that .qrc files are created using Qt Creator.

Can't I create a .qrc file in Qt Designer ? Do I need to use Qt Creator to create a .qrc file and then use it in QT Designer ?

I am using Qt Designer with PyQt in CentOS 7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Qt Creator, since Qt Designer is built in and you can simply create resource files. However, if that's not possible for you, here's a simple qrc data file contents that you can use: -

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

It creates a prefix called "/images/", ready to add images to the resource. Just create a file with .qrc extension and add that.

Comment: I created a file named np.qrc that has the code you provided and loaded in to resource but there is no prefix created.

Comment: Does the file load when you open it and can you edit it from there?

Comment: I was making some stupid mistake. Its done thanks a ton. Can you tell me how to install QT Creator on Centos 7.0. I have tried the following: yum install qt-creator and also I tried to install it by yum install qt..BTW thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Download it from here: http://qt-project.org/downloads Click on "Show Downloads" at the bottom of the page and then scroll down to the section for Qt Creator. There's a 32 and 64-bit version, as well as the source code.

Answer (score 12):

You only need Qt Designer, and it can be done very easily, like this:

1. Open the Resource Browser (**View** -> **Resource Browser**)
2. Click the **Edit Resources** button (first on the left)
3. Click the **New Resource File** button (first on the left)
4. Enter a file name (e.g. *resources.qrc*) and click **Save**
5. Click the **Add Prefix** button (fourth from the left) and enter a name (e.g. *images*)
6. Click the **Add Files** button (fifth from the left) and add your resources

Answer (score 11):

## Using Qt Creator.

(Using the Qt Designer that is inside of Qt creator)

1. **Right clicking** on your project
2. **Add new**
3. Step on the left option **QT**
4. **Qt Resource file**
5. Follow the wizard to add one

> I took those instructions from the video [QT Resource Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWIQIi4lg58)