# How to display .png image using image provider with detail explanation

Tags: qt

i want to send the dynamic image to qml and display on Qt gui i read online image provider is way to solve this issue but i want any sample and simple application which does this.

Comment: The approach that I use to show png images, was using `QLabel` and enabling `pixmap`, after this just selecting the png resource.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt/QML : Send QImage From C++ to QML and Display The QImage On GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691414/qt-qml-send-qimage-from-c-to-qml-and-display-the-qimage-on-gui)

Comment: @Farshid616 i gone through that link as i am beginner to QT i am not much clear, its better if i get any reference code.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/examples/quick/imageprovider?h=5.15). The explanation is [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html#an-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an image provider class where you load your image, this is a simplified example.

qmlimageprovider.h

```
#ifndef QMLIMAGEPROVIDER_H
#define QMLIMAGEPROVIDER_H
#include <QQuickImageProvider>


class QmlImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    QmlImageProvider();
    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize) override;
    void updateImage(QImage new_image);

private:
    QImage image;
};

#endif // QMLIMAGEPROVIDER_H
```

qmlimageprovider.cpp

```
#include "qmlimageprovider.h"

QmlImageProvider::QmlImageProvider()
 : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image)
{
}

QImage QmlImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    image.load("/home/ubuntu/music.jpg");
    return image;
}

void QmlImageProvider::updateImage(QImage new_image)
{
    image = new_image;
}
```

Then you should register this class to your QML engine.

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "qmlimageprovider.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("imageprovider"),
                            new QmlImageProvider());

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Finally you can use **imageprovider** in your qml page and don't forget to write image reload function because images will be cache and you need to reload in order to change them.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3


Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Connections {
        target: imageprovider
        onNewFrameReceived: image.reload();
    }
    Item {
        id: name
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        Rectangle
        {
            id: progressBackground
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width
            Text {
                id: text
                text: qsTr("click to show")
                color: "#c400c4"
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: progressArea
                anchors.fill: progressBackground
                onClicked:
                {
                    image.source = "image://imageprovider/cover"
                }
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: image
            anchors.left: text.right
            source: ""
            cache: false
            function reload() {
                var oldSource = source;
                source = "";
                source = oldSource;
                console.log("reload")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call imageprovider update function to change the image.

Comment: Thanks but while compiling this source code i am facing error : QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:-1 File not found
I am using QT 5.12.9 version

Comment: You should add a resource file to your project, then add main.qml to your resource file. Follow this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/41578261/3365136

Comment: Thanks Thanks a lot for you help. Instead of  image.load("/home/ubuntu/music.jpg"); function i am trying to read the image from socket. but it showing me  error

Comment: Please ask another question about read image from socket and community will answer you because it's a new question outside of this topic.